# Model-View-Controller with a Sqlite database

Tags: ios, sqlite, model-view-controller

i have tons of questions regarding iOS development. I am developing an application 
right now and i am using the MVC pattern along with a database.db (SQLITE). My question is simple: Is the Database the actual model or do i have to create a model too?. I mean should i have the model ( person with name, last name, age,etc) and then the database file as well. If thats the case, how do i relate the model with the database?.

Thanks!

Comment: It's up to you to define "model" -- however you wish.

Comment: Your second option (to have a model class named person that has iVars name, last name, age,etc) sounds to me like the way to go. For the database, it depends on the details of it. You should look up some tutorials on how to retrieve data from a database and just add it to your class.

Comment: The database will actually store the Name, Last name, age etc of a person. Thats my of my question about either having both the model and the database or just a database

Comment: I guess you can do that, but I like to simplify things and use an objective c class as a middleman. You can do whatever u like tho

Comment: Since you are using Model-View-Controller pattern, as well using Object Oriental in data layer side which mean create all related POCO models. Normally we have View Models communicate with User interface and Data Models communicate to database. Between this two have at least business layer to make the binding.

Comment: so i can use it in both ways. The issue is that i am not sure how to create a model and then "link" the database to the model